# How to get all items provided by sharepoint based on its basetype

Tags: sharepoint

I need to get the list of items provided by sharepoint. For ex., If I create a document library, here the item is will be a document. Similarly, if I create a picture library, the item will be picture and if I create a pages library, the item will be Page and so on. I want to get the list of all these items such as Page, Document, Image, Contact etc. using Sharepoint Object Model.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

```
GetAllSubSitesListsAndContentTypesUnderContext()
{
SPWebCollection subSites = siteCollection.AllWebs;

for (int i = 0; i < subSites.Count; i++)
{
System.Console.WriteLine(“…” + subSites[i].Title.ToString() + ” – Site”);

            SPListCollection lists = subSites[i].Lists;
            for (int j = 0; j < lists.Count; j++)
{
System.Console.WriteLine(“……” + lists[j].Title.ToString() + ” – List”);

                  SPContentTypeCollection types = lists[j].ContentTypes;
                  for (int k = 0; k < types.Count; k++)
                  {
System.Console.WriteLine(“………” + types[k].Name.ToString() + ” – Content Type”);
                  }
}
subSites[i].Dispose()
}
}
```

Comment: Please make sure to dispose all webs you touch... This code can leak some memory

Comment: thnaks for the code. It works fine. Is it possible to get the contenttype collection without looping through all sites and lists?

Comment: Thanks heiko Yeah i had actually missed them in hurry to create a dummy method

Comment: you can try the following code       SPWeb objweb = SPContext.Current.Web;

            PContentTypeCollection types = objweb.AvailableContentTypes;

Comment: but i don't think this will reduce a lot of effort as still you would have to loop through all webs